# What is the difference between ECPs and ADF frozen cores?

Tags: computational-chemistry, density-functional-theory

As the title suggests, what are the differences between the frozen core approximation as implemented by Amsterdam Density Functional and effective core potentials (ECPs)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frozen core approximations use explicit orbitals for each core electron, which leads to explicit Coulombic potential terms:
$$ \langle v|V_{val,core}|w\rangle = \sum_{i\in core} \int \frac{v^\ast(r)w(r)|\phi_i(r_1)|^2}{\|r-r_1\|}-\frac{v^\ast(r)\phi_i(r)\phi_i^\ast(r_1)w(r_1)}{\|r-r_1\|}d^3r_1d^3r$$

Effective core potentials model the potential directly instead. See [here](http://www.ccc.uga.edu/lec_top/rltvt/node22.html) for a discussion of effective core potentials.